# Google Maps in a order form with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I've made an order form with 5 steps, on step 2 there is a Google Maps V2 to point the adress of sale.

Now i've added this code to the form: http://jsfiddle.net/davidoleary/cTDvd, but now Maps is not showing up anymore. But when i remove the jquery.min.js maps is working fine, but the code offcourse not.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone now that there is a problem with Jquery and Maps, and of course a solution?

Comment: That fiddle is wrong. `<script>` tags cannot exist in the javascript portion. Without them, the code works fine. Let's see how you *invoke* your maps. Also..it looks as if you're using jQuery 1.6.3; which has deprecated features (and some non-existent) as of jQuery 1.9. In your fiddle, you choose `Edge` which is the most latest released alpha-build of jQuery. What's going on here?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I get `copyText is undefined`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy , thank you for the answer. That it was one edge was not ment to be, i've change it.

The script in fiddle, is working for me in my one script, where the <script> tags are needed. The only problem is, that the two are not working together, it is maps, ore divs with the option value. But i'm needing these two both... How can i show you the problem the best?

Comment: @user2001054 Show me how you invoke your `google map`. Many methods are available. We'll also need to know if any errors exist in the console.

Comment: Using jquery, <div id="canvas">, and in the script it is by this: <script
 src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=<?php echo $this->params->get('map_api_key');?>"
 type="text/javascript"></script>

You mean that?

Comment: is'nt there a part of the .js file that i'm needing for the divs to work correctly that i can include in the page you think, instead of the whole /jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a problem using JQuery and google maps:

http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-basic-example.html

As stated before; why using such an old JQuery library?

Looks like google maps api v2 will not work after may19 2013.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/

So if you'd like your page to work for longer than a couple of months I suggest using a newer version.